# Ubuntu Core 22 installation stuck on raspberry pi4 B

Tags: 22.04, raspberrypi, ubuntu-core

My Raspberry Pi 4 is stuck at this point while installing Ubuntu Core 22 as shown in the attached image.

[image: ubuntu core 22 installation stuck at a point on Raspberry Pi 4b]

I waited for about 2 hours, but cannot see any progress. I wrote the Ubuntu Core image using Raspberry Pi Imager and with the options `Other-general-purpose-OS` -> *Ubuntu* and then chose Ubuntu Core 22.04 64-bit from there.
Previously I tried to write the image manually from the *Use Custom* option on Raspberry Pi Imager and selecting the downloaded ubuntu-core-22-arm64-raspi-lts-10yr.img.xz image. The same thing happened during the installation. Can anyone please suggest me how should I proceed?

Device specs:

- Raspberry Pi 4B
- RAM: 4GB
- Installed OS: Ubuntu Core 22 (64-bit) from Raspberry Pi Imager

Comment: Are you following the official install tutorial? https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi-core

Comment: Note that the tutorial suggests: "*Choose “Ubuntu Core 32-bit armh” for the widest compatibility or “Ubuntu Core 20 64-bit IoT OS for arm64” if you need applications that require a 64-bit system*" Have you tried the 32-bit image to see if you have the same problem?

Comment: I also tried to install the ubuntu core 22 (32bit) but face same issue. I noticed that there some message, showing 
"taskrunner.go : [change 2 "Setup system for run mode" task] failed: Can not make system runnable: your EEPROM does not support tryboot please upgrade to a newer one before installaing Ubuntu Core. See http://forum.snapcraft.io/t/29455 for more details" 
So, later I installed the ubuntu Core 20 (64bit) and followed the official ubuntu core installation instruction, that booted properly.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few notes and a potential resolution walkthrough.

The friendly splash-screen can be dismissed to see installation details. With a keyboard attached, press **Esc** to see those details.  Unlike previous PIs, Raspberry Pi 4B has EEPROM.  Ubuntu Core 22 requires that EEPROM to be a version newer than March 2021.  So, it is very likely the 'stuck' installation is providing the following URL https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/29455 which calls out this requirement.

Having recently walked through this, I found the easiest way to update the EEPROM is to install a current Raspberry Pi OS provided through the Raspberry Pi Imager.  I chose to use Raspberry Pi OS Lite but you may prefer an installation with a desktop (GUI).

With the PI powered on and connected to a network with Internet access:

1. Login to the Raspberry Pi OS.  If running GUI, launch Terminal.
2. Swith to root with `sudo -i`.
3. Check current version of EEPROM with `rpi-eeprom-update`.
   This tool will display if an update is available or if your Pi is up-to-date.
   Proceed if an update is available.
4. Run `apt-get update` to prepare for system upgrade.
5. Upgrade the system (including firmware) with `apt-get full-upgrade`.
6. Reboot the system with `reboot`
7. After reboot, login and verify the EEPROM is current `sudo rpi-eeprom-update`.

When EEPROM is current, you should be able to proceed with Ubuntu Core 22.